# PHP DOM remove (parent) tags

Tags: php, arrays, dom, preg-replace

**Update:**

I have multiple strings in a text like this:

```
<p>[code]</p>
<p>&nbsp;[code]&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;[code]</p>
<p>[code]&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;[code]<br />&nbsp;</p>
```

in the case of [code] I want to remove the surrounding paragraph, spaces and if possible the line-break. Only [code] has to survive.

How do I do it?

**Old example:**

I have this HTML which is produced in CKeditor:

```
<p>This is a line of text.</p>
<p>[youtube:youtubId]</p>
<p>This is a line of text.</p>
<p>[youtube:youtubId]</p>
<p>This is a line of text.</p>
<p>[youtube:youtubId]</p>
<p>This is a line of text.</p>
```

In my CMS I use the square brackets to define plugins. These codes are replaced by PHP code, in this case a little script that shows the youtube thumbnail, clickable to view the movie in a lightbox. Off course there are more kinds of plugins.

What I do is create an array from these HTML:

```
$_parts = preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $cntnt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

This gives me:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string '<p>This is a line of text.</p>  <p>' (length=35)
  1 => string '[youtube:youtubeId]' (length=19)
  2 => string '</p>  <p>This is a line of text.</p>  <p>' (length=41)
  3 => string '[youtube:youtubeId]' (length=19)
  4 => string '</p>  <p>This is a line of text.</p>  <p>' (length=41)
  5 => string '[youtube:youtubeId]' (length=19)
  6 => string '</p>  <p>This is a line of text.</p>' (length=36)
```

When I replace the placeholders [youtube:youtubId] with code containing divs or iframes the HTML code is not valid anymore because the newly inserted code is surrounded with paragraphs.

I would like to remove these from my array, but only the paragraps surrounding the placeholders.

How can I do that efficiently without affecting the paragraph tags in the other lines of text?

Comment: Why do you care what's around it? Just replace what matches your rules with the youtube link/lightbox etc.

Comment: It is not HTML valid to place a DIV or iFrame within p(aragraphs).

Answer (score 0):

You can `str_replace` on the original HTML to remove the `<p>` tags:

```
$noTagsCntnt = str_replace( array("<p>[", "]</p>"), array("[", "]"), $cntnt );
$_parts = preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $noTagsCntnt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

**Edit**

You could try closing the `<p>` before the shortcode, if you are sure that there is an opening `<p>` tag before it.

```
$noTagsCntnt = str_replace( array("[", "]"), array("</p>[", "]<p>"), $cntnt );
```

Then CSS to avoid the extra white space from the empty `<p>` tags:

```
p:empty { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
```

**Edit**

See [CKEditor bug](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/529)

Comment: This works, thank you for your feedback, but when there is a space or other character before or after the bracket breaks again.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but it adds a problem to the solution and solves it then. There must be a more efficiënt way I think.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use preg_split, using preg_replace is more easy:

```
$pattern = '~(<p>)?\[youtube:([^]]+)](?(1)</p>)~';
$replacement = '<iframe width="425" height="344" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?fs=1&quot; frameborder="0" allowFullScreen=""></iframe>';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
```